# How to reuse function codes in python

Tags: python, function, reusability

I have a basic function with following codes:

```
def func_0():
    codes_segment_a
    codes_segment_b
    codes_segment_c
```

Many other small functions share the codes with the func_0, but many add some new codes.
Take the following function as an example:

```
def func_x():
    new codes...
    codes_segment_a
    codes_segment_b
    new codes...
    codes_segment_c
```

The simpliest and most tedicous solution I figure out is to copy and paste the shared codes.
But it looks so stupid because I have more then 20 such functions.

I am quit new in python and please give me some suggestions.
Detailed explaination or examples are quite preferred.
Thanks.

Comment: Make those code segments functions if you reuse them a lot, that's why functions exist!

Comment: Why not [OOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming)?

Comment: These shared code segments are quite short, say, 4~6 sentence long.

Comment: Hence, making these code segments functions seems not so concise compared with the copy/paste way...

Comment: These functions are in fact inner function of a class. Hence I hesitate to use OOP to organize these functions as new class, though it's quite nice to use Inheritance to implement my work.

Answer (score 3):

One general approach is to use classes and inheritance.  A super-simplified example (but see [Classes](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html) for how to use classes and inheritance properly):

```
class Reuse(object):
    def square(self, x):
        return x**2

class Specific(Reuse):
    def times3(self,x):
        return x*3

sp = Specific()
print(sp.times3(4))
```

12

```
print(sp.square(4))
```

16

If you put utility functions in a "top-level" class, and then make new  classes that inherit from that one but that contain the specific functions you want, then you only need to make the utility functions once.  There's nothing wrong with making very short functions, even 3-4 lines long, because it can improve readability and efficiency.

Comment: These functions are in fact inner function of a class. Hence I hesitate to use OOP to organize these functions as new class, though it's quite nice to use Inheritance to implement my work. Do you still suggest use of OOP in this case? thanks.

Comment: From your description, that's exactly the right time to use inheritance